# Sending name of the file then file itself

Tags: java, file, sockets

I want to make my server to be able to get the name of the file that will be sent to it and then after getting that file it could save it in new location with right name.

Here is the server code:

```
class TheServer {

    public void setUp() throws IOException { // this method is called from Main class.
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1991);
        System.out.println("Server setup and listening...");
        Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connect");
        System.out.println("Socket is closed = " + serverSocket.isClosed());



        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String str = rd.readLine();
        System.out.println("Recieved: " + str);
        rd.close();



        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

        int bufferSize = connection.getReceiveBufferSize();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/" + str);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);


        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

        int count;

        while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        is.close();
        connection.close();
        serverSocket.close();


    }
}
```

and here is the client code:

```
public class TheClient {

    public void send(File file) throws UnknownHostException, IOException { // this method is called from Main class.
        Socket socket = null;
        String host = "127.0.0.1";

        socket = new Socket(host, 1991);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("File is too large.");
        }

        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        wr.write(file.getName());
        wr.flush();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        int count;

        while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }


        out.flush();
        out.close();
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

I made few test of my own and it seems that my client is sending the name of the file right, but somehow server gets it wrong. For example if my client tells that name of the file is "test.txt" my server gets it for example like "test.txt´--------------------" or "test.txtPK". I can't understand why it does't get the name normally. Anyone knows why this happens? Or is there an easier way to do this? And my second question is, how can I use this not only in localhost but everywhere? I tried changing my host to my IP adress but it didnt work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never send end of line after the filename. Therefore, when server reads using readLine() it will read all characters until it find first end of line which may be somewhere in file content. Sometimes it's after '-----' and sometimes after 'PK'.

Comment: Just call `wr.newLine()` after `wr.write(file.getName())`. Myself, I would probably use some library like Apache Commons IO. It has a lot of useful utilities on top of `java.io` classes.